# $\uparrow$ and $\downarrow$ Sequences of Simple Functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, functions

**Prop:** given a bounded measurable function on a measurable set $E$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then there are sequences of simple functions on $E$ such that one is increasing and one is decreasing and each converge to $f(x)$ uniformly.

$f^+ = max\{f,0\}$ and $f^- = max\{-f,0\}$ both measurable and hence there exists an increasing sequences $\{\Phi_n\}$ and $\{\psi_n\}$ of simple functions on $E$ converging to $f^+$ and $f^-$ respectively,

define $\phi_n = \psi_n - \Phi_n$, then if $f < 0$, we have
$$\phi_n = -\psi_n \rightarrow -f^- = f$$

so $\phi_n$ is decreasing here. Now if $f \geq 0$, so $\psi_n = 0$ for every $n$ and
$$\phi_n = \Phi_n \rightarrow f^+ = f$$

increasing here.

How to combine them to make this true for any $f(x)$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_n(x)=\frac {i-1}{2^{n}} $ if $\frac {i-1}{2^{n}} \leq f(x) <\frac {i}{2^{n}}$, $i\in \mathbb Z$. Since $f$ is bounded there are only a finite number of $i$'s. so $f_n$ is a simple function.  Note that $|f_n(x)-f(x)| \leq \frac 1 {2^{n}}$ so $f_n \to f$ uniformly. Check that $f_n$ is increasing.

If $g_n $ increases to $-f$ uniformly then $-g_n$ decreases to $f$ uniformly.

Comment: My construction does not work. I have to use the Simple Approximation Lemma.